# Modern Sci-fi movie about device that kills people who look at it

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, mystery

I have been searching for this film for at least 8 years now, this film is what I would consider Sci-fi ish, meaning it takes place in a normal world, normal city (unlike say star wars). The plot centers around an entertainment device that makes people sick and kills them when they look at it and it activates. The device is the newest thing to hit the market and everybody buys it, but a lot more old people are suddenly dying and some are even just found on their couches dead of no apparent cause. I have listed below a few scenes that stick out in my memory.

- The main character who is trying to figure out why all of these people are sick works in medicine. There is a scene I remember where he is on an ambulance and does some risky medical procedure to save the life of one of these mysterious death victims, but his boss is like "it worked this time, if you do it again you are fired"
- There is an autopsy scene where they open up one of the victims found dead on their couch and their entire inside body is completely dry except for one organ. It's almost like all their organs turned to stone except for one that oozes when they cut into it.
- There is another scene where a grandpa or uncle or someone buys an autistic kid this device to play with. The kid likes taking computers apart and stuff but when he took apart this device, he told his grandpa he didn't like it and that it was too complicated.
- I think I remember this device being black with like a big red dot on it, and the dot turns red when it's killing people when they look at it. The device is marketed as an entertainment device that you put on your TV and it is all the rage, everyone has it.
- The film looked new, meaning it must have been made after 1990.

I know that's not a lot but it was a while ago, I never got to see how it ended, and I can't seem to find this film no matter what I Google! I watched it on TV (not in the movies) so I don't know if it's like an Indie movie or like a straight to Television kinda thing. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That's a nice question with every detail. +1

Comment: I think [someone asked about this before](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11919/movie-where-a-red-light-on-a-tv-turns-people-watching-it-into-dust), though this question is much more detailed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like the TV movie [Fatal Error](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0171689/combined) (AKA Reaper) from 1999. From [Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/fatal-error-reaper/):

> A technological nightmare becomes a terrifying reality in this sci-fi-thriller. When a group of computer experts and executives from a high-tech firm based in Seattle die suddenly and unexpectedly during a conference call, Samantha Craig (Janine Turner), a government agent who specializes in disease tracking, is brought in to investigate. Craig finds herself having to work alongside **Dr. Nick Baldwin (Antonio Sabato Jr.), a local physician trying to live down a professional disgrace, and together they make a shocking discovery: a deranged genius has developed a computer virus that has evolved from destroying databases into an organic virus that can claim human lives.** But who would create such a contagion, and how can it be stopped? Fatal Error also stars Robert Wagner and Malcolm Stewart.

The evil product is a black box with a red light and it dries people's organs, as you can see in this clip: